# Prometheus 1.5.2 behind Apache 2.4 reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, prometheus

I want to place Prometheus behind an Apache reverse proxy for authentication and access control. This is for the version of Prometheus that comes with Debian Stretch (`prometheus --version` indicates `version 1.5.2+ds (branch: debian/sid, revision: 1.5.2+ds-2+b3)`) and for Apache 2.4.

I already have Prometheus listening on `127.0.0.1:9090` (e.g. according to `netstat -tlpn`) and I have this in my `VirtualHost` configuration:

```
<Location "/prometheus">
  ProxyPass "http://localhost:9090"
  ProxyPassReverse "http://localhost:9090"
</Location>
```

However, when I visit `https://my-server.com/prometheus` a redirect to `https://my-server.com/graph` occurs (by way of HTTP status code 302 and `Location: /graph`), which cannot be served by the reverse proxy in its current configuration.

How can I change the configuration for this version of Prometheus) such that a visit to `https://my-server.com/prometheus` will successfully redirect to `https://my-server.com/prometheus/graph`, i.e. all Prometheus-related "things" will be served under a common URL prefix `/prometheus`?

**UPDATE** One thing that currently puzzles me is that Prometheus' [`CHANGELOG.md`](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) indicates that command line flag `-web.route-prefix` was introduced back in version 1.0.0, but the Debian package's `/etc/default/prometheus` does not mention this flag, although it mentions many others (as if it would not support it despite ostensibly being based on version 1.5.2).

Answer (score 2):

I'm running newer versions of prometheus now, I had this in the 1.X series as well,

> `-web.external-url=https://<proxyhost>/prometheus`

Try and see if it works in your version (I can't find any old documentation online, but some old github [issues](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/1583) seems to relate to it as well).

Comment: Thanks, but that did not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

You must configure also `--web.route-prefix`.

"http://TOTO/prometheus" --> nginx --> "http://localhost:9090" --> prometheus

The solution is:

```
-web.external-url=https://<proxyhost>/prometheus --web.route-prefix=/
```

Comment: Thank you. It's usually stuff like this that makes people run away from infra work

Answer (score 1):

Below config works even without "-web.external-url" option on Prometheus-core side.
You can also redirect Alert Manager within the same VirtualHost.
So on /prometheus/ - is Prometheus and on /manager/ - is the Alert Manager

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    RewriteEngine On
    ProxyPass /prometheus/ http://localhost:9090/
    ProxyPassReverse /prometheus/ http://localhost:9090/
    Redirect "/" "/prometheus/"

    ProxyPass /manager/ http://localhost:9093/
    ProxyPassReverse /manager/ http://localhost:9093/
    Redirect "/#/alerts" "/manager/#/alerts"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following Apache configuration for the reverse proxy (only relevant part shown) solved the problem in my situation (in a somewhat clumsy way):

```
<Location "/">
  Redirect "/alerts" "/prometheus/alerts"
  Redirect "/api" "/prometheus/api"
  Redirect "/config" "/prometheus/config"
  Redirect "/flags" "/prometheus/flags"
  Redirect "/graph" "/prometheus/graph"
  Redirect "/rules" "/prometheus/rules"
  Redirect "/static" "/prometheus/static"
  Redirect "/status" "/prometheus/status"
  Redirect "/targets" "/prometheus/targets"
</Location>
<Location "/prometheus">
  ProxyPass "http://localhost:9090"
  ProxyPassReverse "http://localhost:9090"
</Location>
```